# SQL : select from nested table oid

Tags: sql, database, oracle, object-relational-model

I tried to select from the nested table but  an error message displayed "ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended"
This is the request of selecttion

```
select b.NomPlayer from  table (select t.players from Team t where t.IdTeam=1) as p;
```

And this is the code witch I created the `player_type` and `team_type`

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE Player_Type AS OBJECT ( Num_Licence NUMBER, NomPlayer VARCHAR2(30)) ;
CREATE TYPE PlayersNT AS TABLE OF ref Player_Type ;
CREATE TYPE Team_Type AS OBJECT ( IdTeam NUMBER, TeamName VARCHAR2(30), Players PlayersNT ) ;
CREATE TABLE Player OF Player_Type ;
CREATE TABLE Team OF Team_Type
NESTED TABLE Players STORE AS PlayersTab ;
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `AS` in the `FROM` clause.  Unlike other databases, Oracle only allows `AS` in the `SELECT` clause.

```
select * from table(select t.players from Team t where t.IdTeam=1) p;
```

Comment: I tried this but an error message appeared ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected NUMBER got REF SYSTEM.TEAM_TYPE

Comment: Can you add some sample data to reproduce the new error?  When I run the DDL and query the empty tables it works for me.

Comment: I add the oid's of player in the nested table